# Change dataframe to dictonary on unique column

Tags: python, pandas

I have a data frame-

```
df=pd.DataFrame({'zone':['AA','CC','CC','AA','CC'],'val':[22,14,32,76,9]})
```

Now I want to filter the zone columns and append them into keys of the dictionary with the val column as the items.

Output-

```
{ 'AA': [array(22,76)]
  'CC': [array(14,32,9)]
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do:

```
d = {k:list(x) for k,x in df.groupby('zone')['val']}
```

Output:

```
{'AA': [22, 76], 'CC': [14, 32, 9]}
```

Or to match your output:

```
d = {k:[x.values] for k,x in df.groupby('zone')['val']}
```

Output:

```
{'AA': [array([22, 76])], 'CC': [array([14, 32,  9])]}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try like below:

```
d = {}
for index, row in df.iterrows():
   key = row['zone']
     if key not in d:
       d[key] = [row['val']]
     else:
       d[key].append(row['val'])
```